What heter do Kiruv people (especially) and all of us have, feeding people who probably wont make a Brach
If you have a public/private psak regarding the halacha  please include the Rav's name or sources please.
We all have met this situation in our daily lives…not just in Kiruv…In business, irreligious relatives and friends, kosher supermarkets or liquor stores  with a "taste" counter AND what about Restaurants…How can you provide food and tables to sit down for "non bracha making clientele" The fact they paid for it, does that absolve you?
And does hachnosos orchim trump this Halacha?
Abie
Kitzur Shulchan Orach: 42:15. ( and surely elsewhere)
לֹא יִתֵּן אָדָם לֶאֱכוֹל אֶלָּא לְמִי שֶׁיּוֹדֵעַ בּוֹ שֶׁיִּטּוֹל יָדָיו וִיבָרֵךְ (קס"ט).
Do not serve food to anyone unless you know he will wash his hands and recite the berachah.
Note in Sefaria:
*This is a very difficult issue which can arise in dealing with business associates or with non-religious family members. The matter, when necessary, should be discussed with a competent Halachic authority. See Minchas Shlomo by Rav Shlomo Zalman Auerbach, zt”l Chapter 35.
